# Category images not uploaded in backend

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, category, admin

Recently a client pointed out an issue where they couldn't upload any category images. Editing the category works fine but the image upload doesn't.

The media directory is writable, all other image uploaders seem to work and right now I'm kinda at a loss what to do next.
I've tried small and large images, types JPEG and PNG.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was caused by an image in the media/catalog/category folder called .jpg (so just extension and no filename).
After deleting it I could upload again.

Comment: Please mark this answer as solution

Answer (score 4):

Taking into consideration the fact that image upload is working fine for products we can eliminate an issue with flash uploader and some common issues like GD etc. The list of things to check can be the following:

- verify the existence of media/catalog/category directory with correct permissions
- in case it is media/tmp check also permissions and additionally flush it
- check that you have not ran out of the disc space